# Sum up with the next line into a new colum

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble on figuring out how to create a new column with the sum of 2 subsequent cells.

I have :

```
df1<- tibble(Years=c(1990, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2030, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080),
Values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ))
```

Now, I want a new column where the first line is the sum of 1+2, the second line is the sum of 1+2+3 , the third line is the sum 1+2+3+4 and so on.

As 1, 2, 3, 4... are hipoteticall values, I need to measure the absolute growth from a decade to another in order to create later on a new variable to measure the percentage change from a decade to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the last row is to be repeated. Otherwise the fill part can be skipped.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = lead(cumsum(Values))) %>% 
  fill(x)

#   Years Values     x
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1990      1     3
# 2  2000      2     6
# 3  2010      3    10
# 4  2020      4    15
# 5  2030      5    21
# 6  2050      6    28
# 7  2060      7    36
# 8  2070      8    45
# 9  2080      9    45
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(tibble)
df1<- tibble(Years=c(1990, 2000, 2010, 2020, 2030, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080),
             Values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ))

library(slider)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df1 %>%
  mutate(xx = slide_sum(Values, after = 1, before = Inf))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   Years Values    xx
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1990      1     3
#> 2  2000      2     6
#> 3  2010      3    10
#> 4  2020      4    15
#> 5  2030      5    21
#> 6  2050      6    28
#> 7  2060      7    36
#> 8  2070      8    45
#> 9  2080      9    45
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You want the `cumsum()` function. Here are two ways to do it.

```
### Base R
df1$cumsum <- cumsum(df1$Values)

### Using dplyr
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Values))
```

Here is the output in either case.

```
df1
      # A tibble: 9 x 3
  Years Values cumsum
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1990      1      1
2  2000      2      3
3  2010      3      6
4  2020      4     10
5  2030      5     15
6  2050      6     21
7  2060      7     28
8  2070      8     36
9  2080      9     45
```

Comment: Perhaps OP wants a sliding sum including next value??

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
 v1 <- cumsum(df1$Values)[-1]
df1$new <- c(v1, v1[length(v1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, newCol := shift(cumsum(Values), -1, fill = sum(Values))][]
   Years Values newCol
1:  1990      1      3
2:  2000      2      6
3:  2010      3     10
4:  2020      4     15
5:  2030      5     21
6:  2050      6     28
7:  2060      7     36
8:  2070      8     45
9:  2080      9     45
```

or a base R option following a similar idea

```
transform(
  df,
  newCol = c(cumsum(Values)[-1],sum(Values))
)
```